# How to remove one price in WooCommerce variation variable prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I just have some issue regarding **variation prices**, when I add other than normal price, it showing me two prices (two price on "now" and two price in "was").

What I need only one prices like simple product prices (one price on "now" and one price in "was").

Example : http://dewuchi.com/product/mens/attractive-alex-riley-black-leather-vest/

Answer (score 1):

To only display **minimum price** for a variable products

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
     $price = '';
     $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());

     return $price;
}
```

If you need to display **max price** replace `$price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());` by `$price .= woocommerce_price($product->max_variation_price);`

You can also display the suffix price adding this line `.= $product->get_price_suffix();`  **before** `return $price;`

Note (if you don't know yet): You have to add this code in the function.php file located in your active theme folder (or child theme folder).